# How to make a image pop out inside a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains pictures, and I want them to pop out when I hover over them and they do but they only pop out inside the div but I want them to pop out onto the website. As you can see in the screenshot, you just cant see the picture after you hover over it. Anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Here is my CSS code for my images and gallery

```
#gallery {
  width: 83%;
  margin:auto;
  height: 253px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 -8px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #AAAAAA;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-style: solid;

}

#gallery img{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 325px;
  height: 230px;
  transition: transform .5s;

}
#gallery img:hover{
   transform: scale(1.5);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this 
It's really simple I wrap two boxes into one parent div and if you see here the boxes are pop out when hovering. I just used simple colors here but you can use your images here.

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.child-box1 {
  background: cyan;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.child-box2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
.child-box1:hover,.child-box2:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-box1"></div>
  <div class="child-box2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the z-index property to a higher value on the `img:hover` selector.

I think this Codepen might be referencing what you're looking for: https://codepen.io/ParsonsProjects/pen/OVgMGb

Comment: hmm I tried changing it and it still pops out inside the div and I cant see the picture